# How to draw a 2-dim Brownian motion into a disk

Tags: tikz-pgf, draw

I should draw a Brownian motion starting into a disk until the first exit time from this disk in my LaTeX work (and after i should do similar things with SLE_k), how can i do?

EDIT:
I draw some planar Brownian motion using the following code, the only thing i don't know how to do is to make a circle and find an intersection

```
\documentclass[parskip]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\Emmett}[5]{% points, advance, rand factor, options, end label
\draw[#4] (0,0)
\foreach \x in {1,...,#1}
{   -- ++(rand*#2,rand*#3)
}
node[right] {#5};
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\Emmett{750}{0.1}{0.1}{red}{first one}
\Emmett{750}{0.1}{0.1}{green}{second one}
\Emmett{750}{0.1}{0.1}{blue}{third one}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please help us help you by providing a minimal compilable code example of what you've tried so far (MWE).

Comment: ... and a sketch to show what you want clearer.

Comment: I wrote a paper in .tex ( on overleaf) and i should draw a 2-dim Brownian motion into it, or maybe using some kind of program to make this image (i am a newbie of latex, i'm sorry ):

Comment: I don't want a grafic of a function but a draw of a possible 2-dim Brownian motion, i.e., a grafic in the plane of (B_1(t),B_2(t)) where B_1(t),B_2(t) are two Brownian motion starting at a point |z|<1, until the time that B_1(t)^2 + B_2(t)^2=1, i don't know if it is possible directly on latex

Comment: @ClaudioDelfino Just to note that if you want to modify people, use @ and their username, as I use here.

Comment: @ClaudioDelfino Also, it _is_ possible in LaTeX. But you need a sketch, I'm not an expert in Physics or so... to understand what you said properly.

Comment: For a 1-dim Brownian motion i think one could do in the following way, fix the initial value, i.e. B(0)=x, and then find the random value for a near time, i mean, B(0,0001) is distribuited as Normal distribution with mean 0 and variance 0,0001, then finding B(0,0002) that should be B(0,0001) + another Normal distribution with mean 0 and variance 0,0001 and so on until a time 1 for example

Comment: @Claudio Delfino, do you want the simulation to stop when the first intersection occurs, or do you want all intersections?

Comment: @marmot Actually I have a problem: i thought that the function rand would have given a number with a normal ditribution, instead this function gives a random number in the interval [0,1], but i think one can just handle this using Box-muller transforma and \sqrt(-\log(U_1))\sin(2\pi U_2) where U_1 and U_2 are uniform distribuited in [0,1] as we have

Comment: @marmot Another thing, the case in which we start at (0,0) is the simplest, now i would like to start in any point of the disk, btw i appreciate very much your work, the comments in the code are helping me much

Answer (score 1):

This adds circles around the Brownian motions.

```
\documentclass[parskip]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\begin{document}

\newcommand{\Emmett}[5]{% points, advance, rand factor, options, end label
\begin{scope}[local bounding box=Emmett]
\draw[#4] (0,0)
\foreach \x in {1,...,#1}
{   -- ++(rand*#2,rand*#3)
} coordinate(Emmett-last);
\end{scope}
\node[anchor=west,#4] at (Emmett-last) {#5};
\node[circle,draw,#4,fit=(Emmett.south west) (Emmett.north east),inner sep=0.5pt]{};
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\Emmett{750}{0.1}{0.1}{red}{first one}
\Emmett{750}{0.1}{0.1}{green}{second one}
\Emmett{750}{0.1}{0.1}{blue}{third one}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

I do, however, not quite understand what you mean by intersections. Something like this perhaps?

```
\documentclass[parskip]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,intersections}
\begin{document}

\newcommand{\Emmett}[6]{% points, advance, rand factor, options, end label
\begin{scope}[local bounding box=Emmett]
\draw[#4] (0,0)
\foreach \x in {1,...,#1}
{   -- ++(rand*#2,rand*#3)
} coordinate(Emmett-last);
\end{scope}
\node[anchor=west,#4] at (Emmett-last) {#5};
\node[name path=#6,circle,draw,#4,fit=(Emmett.south west) (Emmett.north east),inner sep=0.5pt]{};
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\Emmett{750}{0.1}{0.1}{red}{first one}{first}
\Emmett{750}{0.1}{0.1}{green}{second one}{second}
\Emmett{750}{0.1}{0.1}{blue}{third one}{third}
\fill[name intersections={of=first and second}] (intersection-1) circle(1pt)
(intersection-2) circle(1pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I've put together a command using the basic layer of pgf (the front end tikz didn't provide quite enough flexibility for your problem). When called from a `pgfpicture` environment, it starts the Brownian motion from the centre of the disc and continues until an intersection occurs. The coordinates of the intersection point are then printed. A number of walks can be run on the same disc (in different colours).

I hadn't done any work with the pgf basic layer before so it is quite likely that improvements can be made to the code (open to suggestions here). 
I've tried to comment the code but will admit the pgf layer syntax can appear quite alien if you are only familiar with the front end. Here I will summarise the salient points:

- The tikz `intersections` library is used to calculate the intersection of two paths (the disc and a walk). See p.1058 of the tikz manual (V. 3.1).
- The pgf command `\pgfgetlastxy` provides access to the last coordinates of a path, and is the key player in the `\foreach` loop used to construct the walk
- At each step, the distance of the walk from the origin can be calculated, allowing us to terminate the walk if it has gone outside of the disc.

The code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz} % Includes the basic layer (pgf) and mathematical engine
% Library to determine points of intersection of two paths
\usetikzlibrary{intersections} % See manual p.1058
% Command to be used inside a pgfpicture. Requires tikz, tikz.intersections
\newcommand\discmotion[4]
{ % #1: Walk number (currently only used to make sure intersection points are printed in different places)
  % #2: Number of steps in walk
  % #3: If 1, Terminate after first intersection. 0 (or any other integer): Always complete walk.
  % #4: Path color (intersections always circled in red)
\pgfintersectionsortbyfirstpath % If multiple intersections, order according to first path (the random walk)
\pgfintersectionofpaths % Record intersections between the following two paths \pgfintersectionofpaths{PATH 1}{PATH 2}
{
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointorigin} % Start path at origin
    \foreach \x in {1,...,#2} % Walk loop
    {
        \pgfgetlastxy{\macrox}{\macroy} % Get coordinates from last step
        \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\dist}{veclen(\macrox,\macroy)} % Calculate distance from origin (pt)
        \ifnum#3=1\relax % Only check if outside disc if #3 has a value of 1
            \ifdim  \dist < 50pt % Check whether path has gone outside disc
                \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointadd{\pgfpoint{\macrox}{\macroy}}{\pgfpoint{rand*10}{rand*10}}} % Add random vector onto path
            \fi
        \else % Otherwise always continue path
                \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointadd{\pgfpoint{\macrox}{\macroy}}{\pgfpoint{rand*10}{rand*10}}}
        \fi
    }
    % Now actually draw the path
    \color{#4}  % Change color temporarily
    \pgfgetpath\temppath
    \pgfusepath{stroke}
    \pgfsetpath\temppath
    \color{black} % Restore color (for circle)
}
{
    % Path for disc
    \pgfpathcircle{\pgfpointorigin}{50pt}
    \pgfgetpath\temppath
    \pgfusepath{stroke}
    \pgfsetpath\temppath
}
% Lengths to store intersections points (origin = centre of disc), in pt.
\newdimen\xintersect
\newdimen\yintersect
\pgfintersectionsortbyfirstpath % Repeat of earlier command to be sure :)
\foreach \s in {1,...,\pgfintersectionsolutions} % Iterate through intersection object (list of coordinates)
{
    \pgfpathcircle{\pgfpointintersectionsolution{\s}}{2pt} % Circle the intersection point
    \pgfextractx{\xintersect}{\pgfpointintersectionsolution{\s}} % Get x coordinate of current intersection
    \pgfextractx{\yintersect}{\pgfpointintersectionsolution{\s}} % Get y coordinate of current intersection
    % Add a text object to right of disc, using \pgfmathparse to change the coordinates in pt to cm (precision 4)
    \pgftext[at=\pgfpointscale{0.5}{% Just some scaling
    \pgfpointadd{\pgfpointadd{\pgfpoint{0cm}{6cm}}{\pgfpoint{0cm}{-#1 cm}}}{\pgfpoint{12cm}{-\s cm}}}] % {test}
        {\small#4: $x=$\pgfmathparse{\xintersect/28.45274}\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed,precision=4]{\pgfmathresult} $y=$\pgfmathparse{\yintersect/28.45274}\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed,precision=4]{\pgfmathresult}}
}
\color{red}
% \pgfusepath{fill} % Fill intersection circles (instead of stroke)
\pgfusepath{stroke} % Draw intersection paths  \pgfusepath{fill} could be used here
\color{black} % Restore color
}
\begin{document}
\begin{pgfpicture}
\discmotion{1}{250}{1}{black}
\discmotion{2}{250}{1}{blue}
\discmotion{3}{250}{1}{orange}
\end{pgfpicture}
\end{document}
```

Example output with above code:

[image: output]

Note that the step sizes are quite large (`rand*10`); you may want to reduce this. You may also want to add additional arguments, specifying the radius of the disc, for example (currently fixed at `50pt`). Lastly, there is also the option to not stop at the firsrt intersection, but always complete the prescribed number of steps (recording *all* intersections). Change the first argument from 1 to use this. For example,

```
\begin{pgfpicture}
\discmotion{1}{200}{0}{black} % Don't stop until 200!
\end{pgfpicture}
```

just produced

[image: output2]