# Showing dots in a path draw

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-path

I would like to modify the command \Emmet of the [following post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/475202/how-to-draw-a-2-dim-brownian-motion-into-a-disk) so that the consecutive dots are shown by, say, a small colored bullet (obviously I will use the command with fewer dots so that one can actually see something). I guess there is a simple solution to do so but I did not find it ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code modified from [How to draw a 2-dim Brownian motion into a disk](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/475202/how-to-draw-a-2-dim-brownian-motion-into-a-disk)

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\Emmett}[5]{% points, advance, rand factor, options, end label
\draw[#4, fill] (0,0)
\foreach \x in {1,...,#1}
{   -- ++(rand*#2, rand*#3) circle[radius=0.02]
}
node[right] {#5};
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\Emmett{75}{0.1}{0.1}{red}{first one}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Random line with dots]